# Cygwin gcc 4.8.3 version fails to make

Tags: gcc, g++, cygwin

I have been trying to **compile/make** **'gcc 4.8.3'**on cygwin. The version of the cygwin which I have installed is **cygwin x86_64**. I also have pre installed gcc, which is version 5.4.0.

Why I want this particular version of gcc is because, I need to install **Python3.5.2**, so that I can in turn, **install tensorflow on cygwin**. I triled installing Python3.5.2 using Pyenv, but my guess is that the library for Python 3.5.2 is pre compiled with gcc 4.8.x versions, as I faced the issue that Pyenv could not run the C compiled programs. Also, I think, the issue might be because of the versions. I am using windos 10, which is 64 bit.

The configuration of gcc happens successfully, but I am facing an issue while running the make file. This is the error message:

```
          checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
          configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
          See `config.log' for more details.
          make[2]: *** [Makefile:4763: configure-stage1-gmp] Error 1
          make[2]: Leaving directory 
          '/cygdrive/c/softwares/cygwin64/lib/gcc_4_8_3'
          make[1]: *** [Makefile:20946: stage1-bubble] Error 2
          make[1]: Leaving directory 
          '/cygdrive/c/softwares/cygwin64/lib/gcc_4_8_3'
           make: *** [Makefile:890: all] Error 2
```

I checked the config.log, and this is what I have found:

```
           /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:45:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such 
           file or directory
           #include <stddef.h>
                ^
           compilation terminated.
           configure:12120 $? = 1
           configure: failed program was:

            | /* confdefs.h.  */
            | #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU MP"
            | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gmp"
            | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.3.2"
            | #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU MP 4.3.2"
            | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "gmp-bugs@gmplib.org"
            | #define PACKAGE "gmp"
            | #define VERSION "4.3.2"
            | #define WANT_FFT 1
            | #define HAVE_HOST_CPU_none 1
            | #define PROTOTYPES 1
            | #define __PROTOTYPES 1
            | #define STDC_HEADERS 1
            | #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
            | #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
            | #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
            | #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
            | #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
            | #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
            | #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
            | #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
            | #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
            | #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
            | #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
            | /* end confdefs.h.  */
            | #ifdef __STDC__
            | # include <limits.h>
            | #else
            | # include <assert.h>
            | #endif
            |            Syntax error

             configure:12114: g++ -E -DNO_ASM conftest.cpp
             In file included from /usr/include/features.h:12:0,
             from /usr/include/limits.h:11,
             from conftest.cpp:27:
```

I have also included the /lib/cpp dll file in the windows environment path. Still, it did not change anything.

I think that this issue is due to a missing file. In which directory would I be able to locate this file?

Or is there any other mechanism to compile gcc. I don't want to use the preinstalled gcc version, as I intent to install Python 3.5.2 and tensorflow on cygwin.

Any type of help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: $ cygcheck -l gcc-core |grep stddef.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/stddef.h

Answer (score 0):

stddef.h is part of the gcc compiler

```
$ cygcheck -l gcc-core |grep stddef.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/stddef.h
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix for my problem.

I have uninstalled the cygwin Python with apt-cyg and now, the windows version of python is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, an alternative is to install python using `setupx86_64.exe` and symlink the binaries manually in `.pyenv/versions/<yourversionname>/bin`: refer to the question [Pyenv fails to install python on Cygwin: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161503/pyenv-fails-to-install-python-on-cygwin-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named)